# C# MapControl How to prevent image from changing size while zooming?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I added image to MapControl but while zooming map in and out, image is changing size.

```
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/weii.png"));
        img.Opacity = 0.1;
        img.Stretch = Stretch.None;


        MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(img, new Point(0.5, 0.5));
        MapControl.SetLocation(img, new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 51.236852, Longitude = 22.548944 }));

        mapa.Children.Add(img);
```

How can I made image to not change size?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are seeing an optical illusion that may be caused by an incorrect anchor point. When the anchor point is not positioned in the correct location, the pushpin image will appear to drift and possibly look like it might be changing size slightly. Your current code is anchoring the image on the center of the image. Take a look at this blog post for information on how to properly anchor pushpins: https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2014/10/02/correcting-anchoring-pushpins-to-the-map/

Comment: It is not optical illusion. Image really changes size while zooming map in and out. Image is anchored to the point on the MapControl specified by the MapControl.Location.

Comment: I've just ran your code on my Windows Phone and it works perfectly fine. The image doesn't change size. Are you running your code in an emulator or on an actual device?

Also worth noting, you should target Win10 rather than WP8.1 as WP8.1 market share is shrinking fast as those still on Windows Phone 8.1 are installing the update.

Comment: I am runnig code on device with Win10. [link](http://imgur.com/a/37Bdl) here is how it works for me.

Comment: As I suspected, this is an optical illusion, or a misunderstanding on your side. The image is not changing size when you zoom. It is staying the same size regardless of the zoom level, which is exactly what your code is meant to do. I suspect you want to be able to scale the image based on the zoom level. To achieve this you need to add logic to scale the size of the image based as the map is zoomed. Here is a Win8 sample that does exactly what you want. Should be fairly easy to migrate to Win10: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Image-Overlays-in-Bing-a0a3471e?redir=0

Comment: Thank you for your help. You were right. Link was very helpful. With help of another person I managed to rewrite the code to make it work.